# How to show that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\log\big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{x_i}}\big]$ is convex on dom$f=\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

for now I've got the following: set $y_i=e^{x_i}\quad\Rightarrow \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_i}=y_i\quad \Rightarrow$

$\nabla_x f=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_i}}[y_1\; \dots\; y_n]^\top\quad\Rightarrow$

$\nabla_x^2f_{ij}=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{\big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{y_k}\big)^2}y_i(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{y_k}-y_i), &\forall\; i=j\\ -\frac{1}{\big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{y_k}\big)^2}y_iy_j, & \forall\; i\neq j \end{cases}$

Now I need to show that $\nabla_x^2f$ is positive semidefinite, but I'm stuck here.
Also tried first order conditions and direct proof by definition of convexity, but also stuck there.

Comment: What's $e_i^x$? Did you mean $e^{x_i}$?

Comment: yes, corrected this.

Comment: I have read in Boyd that sum of convex functions are convex, I mean summation preserve convexity which is easy to show. also, there is another feature that says log( a convex  function) is also convex. you can find them on boyd book.

Comment: This is incorrect, the logarithm of a convex function is not necessarily convex.

Comment: @Cardinal Simple conterexample: $f(x)=x$ is convex, but $\ln(x)$ is not. You seem to think of [log-convex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function).

Comment: @A.G. you mean it is concave ? however, f(x)=x is not convex in your contex and must be considered as a affine function

Comment: @A.G. I meant convex and concave are relative. I mean - convex = concave

Comment: @Cardinal $f(x)=x$ is most certainly convex. It is also concave, of course, and affine.

Comment: But fine, another counterexample: $f(x)=x^2$. Its logarithm is not convex.

Comment: OK you are right. just never forget convex and concave differs only in one single minus. So, you can easily prove convexity by concavity. Let finish this stupid discussion here

Comment: The proof can be made in one line if one accepts that the sum of log-convex is log-convex. Just note that each $e^{x_i}$ is log-convex. To prove the statement about the sum is a bit longer (takes several lines). See [Proposition 6.3.4., Part (e)](https://books.google.se/books?id=1U5GAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=sv&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q&f=false) with the proof on the next page.

Comment: @A.G. pages you referred to are not displayed

Comment: @hsydreba ok, Sketch: $f,g$ log-convex, i.e. $f=e^F$, $g=e^G$ for convex $F,G$. We need to prove $\ln(f+g)=\ln(e^F+e^G)$ convex, but it is the composition of convex and increasing in each argument $\ln(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})$ and convex $F,G$, thus, convex (the composition rule).

Comment: You should have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $S=\sum_i y_i$; then
$$\nabla^2 f(x) = S^{-2} ( S \mathop{\textrm{diag}}(y) - yy^T )$$
Now let's show that $\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq 0$; or, equivalently, that $v^T\left(\nabla^2 f(x)\right) v \geq 0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We have
$$ S^2 v^T (\nabla^2 f(x) ) v =  v^T (S \mathop{\textrm{diag}}(y) - yy^T) v = \sum_i y_i \cdot \sum_i y_i v_i^2 - \left(\sum_i y_i v_i\right)^2$$
This quantity is nonnegative. To see why,
define $z_i=y_i^{1/2}$ and $w_i=y_i^{1/2}v_i$, $i=1,2,\dots, n$. Then 
$$\sum_i y_i v_i = \sum_i z_i w_i \leq \|z\|_2 \|w\|_2$$
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Squaring both sides we have
$$\left(\sum_i y_i v_i\right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_i z_i^2 \right) \left( \sum_i w_i^2 \right) = \left( \sum_i y_i \right) \left( \sum_i y_i v_i^2 \right)$$
Which establishes that
$$\sum_i y_i v_i^2 - \left(\sum_i y_i v_i\right)^2 \geq 0 
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad v^T(\nabla^2 f(x))v \geq 0$$
The Hessian is positive semidefinite everywhere. Note that it is *not* positive definite; $\nabla^2 f(x)\vec{1}=0$ for all $x$. This function is therefore not strictly convex; just "plain old" convex. :-)

Comment: Belissimo! Thanks!

Comment: A remark : $diag(V)-VV^T$ (the case $S=1$) is the variance matrix of multinomial distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Sketch: Let $a,b\in \mathbb {R}^n.$ It's enough to show $f(a+tb)$ is a convex function of $t\in \mathbb {R}.$ Differentiate this twice with respect to $t$ to see this amounts to showing

$$(\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{a_k + tb_k})(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2e^{a_k + tb_k}) \ge (\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_ke^{a_k + tb_k})^2.$$

This inequality can be viewed as

$$\mu(E)\int_E f^2\,d\mu \ge (\int_E f\,d\mu)^2$$

for the right choices of these symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another approach for those who would like to avoid "messy" job with $n\times n$ Hessians. First we make a remark

**Remark:** It is easy to see that the function $g(t)=\ln(e^t+1)$ is convex and increasing ($g'(t)\ge 0$ and $g''(t)\ge 0$). Thus, the function $g\circ F$ [is convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Convex_function_calculus) for any convex $F$.

Let's prove convexity by induction on the dimension.

**Base $n=2$**: the function 
$$
h_2(x)=\ln(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})=\ln\Bigl((e^{x_1-x_2}+1)e^{x_2}\Bigr)=\ln(e^{x_1-x_2}+1)+x_2
$$
is convex by the remark above where $F(x)=x_1-x_2$.

**Step $n-1$ to $n$**: do the same trick with $x_n$
\begin{align}
h_n(x)&=\ln(e^{x_1}+\ldots+e^{x_{n-1}}+e^{x_n})=\\
&=\ln(e^{x_1-x_n}+\ldots+e^{x_{n-1}-x_n}+1)+x_n=\\
&=\ln(e^{\ln(e^{x_1-x_n}+\ldots+e^{x_{n-1}-x_n})}+1)+x_n.
\end{align}
By the same remark above this function is convex if $\ln(e^{x_1-x_n}+\ldots+e^{x_{n-1}-x_n})$ is convex. But the latter is $h_{n-1}(Ax)$ where
$$
A=\left[\matrix{
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & -1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & -1
}\right]
$$
which is a superposition of convex and affine, which is convex.

Comment: Very, very cool.

Comment: Mind blowing approach! Thanks!